# Use CSVReader from opencsv.CSVReader for a String

Tags: java, csv

I would like to use the CSVReader in opencsv to read a string of comma separated values.  I have used this reader with a multipart file in the past wherein the following would be done: 
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(fileName.getInputStream());

This is fine for a multipart file however I cannot find a solution for this if I simply want to pass in a string e.g. one line of CSV's.

Comment: Character set conversions aside, shouldn't something like `new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes())` basically do the job here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `java.io.StringReader`. Example:

```
final String inputString = "value1,value2,value3";

try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(inputString))) {
    // Your code here
}
```